# Module cannot be imported after being renamed

Tags: python, import, module

My Program is very simple, it has two `.py` files in the same folder as:

```
-main.py
-Module.py
```

in the main`.py` I import Module simply like :

```
import Module
```

it used to work until I wanted to rename my Module to something more meaningful. I changed the file name to discriminator`.py` and since then I cannot import it to my `main.py` (I also change the code in `main.py` accordingly by importing the new filename)

the specific error I face is :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discriminator'
```

Comment: are you sure there is no typo in the filename?  please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Did you by mistake used the same session or something similar?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I am sure there is no typo in the filename. The code used to work just some minutes ago with the other name. Now  I have tried many different names but it simply doesnt work

Comment: I copied the whole project to a new folder and it worked again. I think it has something to do with my IDE (using Spyder python 3.7) not updating the module list or something . does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: It can be a console problem, have you used a new one connecting to your code ?